# How can I get the output of intermediate layers for each epoch in Keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a simple sequential model

Following the instruction of keras documentation, the output of intermediate layer can be obtained by:

```
layer_name = 'my_layer'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
```

I can get the output of a trained model now. However, I want to get their output during (for each epoch)

I try to use a *Callback* function to achieve this goal, but it whill only return the output for last trained model.

Another naive way I can think of is saving models for each epoch, but it wastes lots of storage space..

I try to use a *Callback* function to achieve this goal, but it whill only return the output for last trained model.

Another naive way I can think of is saving models for each epoch, but it wastes lots of storage space..

Comment: Callbacks can report information at the end of each epoch, with the on_epoch_end method.

Comment: depends what you aim to do with that intermediate layer value... you can just use `Model(inputs=model.input,outputs=[model.get_layer(layer_name).output, model.layers[-1].output])` and have both as output of the model

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Thanks!! I use this code as extractor `extractor = Model(...)` and use `extractor(x_train)` to finally solve my problem.

Comment: @DorisL you're welcome, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but might still be useful.

The following is for a Keras callback to display the weights and output of a model up through a given layer, assuming named layers.

```
class TrackLayerWeightsAndOutput(Callback):
    def __init__(self, layer_name, sample_input):
        super(TrackLayerWeightsAndOutput, self).__init__()
        self.layer_name = layer_name
        self.sample_input = sample_input # input of some form: (train_x[0:1])

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        layer = self.get_named_layer()
        # re-create model from input --> requested layer.

        self.intermediate_model = Model(inputs=self.model.input,
                                        outputs=layer.output
        )

    
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        '''Called per epoch. '''
        self.print_layer_weights(epoch=epoch)
        self.print_layer_output()
        

    def print_layer_weights(self, epoch):
        weights = self.get_named_layer().get_weights()
        print(f'\nWeights of Layer {self.layer_name} after Epoch {epoch + 1}:')
        for i, weight in enumerate(weights):
            print(f'  Weight {i + 1}: {weight}')

    def print_layer_output(self):
        # Get the output of the specified layer for the sample input
        output = self.intermediate_model.predict(self.sample_input)
        print(f'\nOutput of Layer {self.layer_name} for Sample Input:')
        print(output)

    def get_named_layer(self):
        # assume that you have  named layer, Dense(5, name='layer1')
        return self.model.get_layer(self.layer_name)
```

This can then be passed to a keras.fit, as a callback.  This will drastically slow down training, but allow for better understanding of the network.

```
callback = TrackLayerWeightsAndOutput(layer_name = 'layer1', sample_input = train_x[0:1])
model.fit(<stuff>, callbacks=[callback])
```